# Error in web.xml: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'context-root'

Tags: java, xml

My `ibm-web-ext.xml` file has following code:

```xml
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-ext
    xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-web-ext_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">

    <reload-interval value="3"/>
    <context-root uri="ADRS" />
    <enable-directory-browsing value="true"/>
    <enable-file-serving value="true"/>
    <enable-reloading value="true"/>
    <enable-serving-servlets-by-class-name value="true" />

</web-ext>
```

And my `web.xml` has following code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="ADRS_WebApp" version="2.5" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>ADRS</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/adrs-security.xml
        /WEB-INF/adrs-service-sec.xml
        /WEB-INF/adrs-service.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>adrs</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>adrs</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

<!-- security filters -->
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.do</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

    <session-config>
        <!-- session timeout in minutes -->
        <session-timeout>20</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

</web-app>
```

And I get this following error :

```
  cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'context-root'. One of '{"http://
     websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee":resource-ref, "http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee":servlet-cache-config, 
     "http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee":autoload-filters, "http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee":auto-encode-
     requests, "http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee":auto-encode-responses, "http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/
     javaee":enable-directory-browsing, "http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee":enable-file-serving, "http://
     websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee":pre-compile-jsps, "http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee":enable-reloading, 
     "http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee":enable-serving-servlets-by-class-name}' is expected.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the following. In stead of version version="2.5", version="3.0" and accordingly xsd will be modified.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<!-- other code here -->

</web-app>
```

Try with the following `ibm-web-ext.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-ext
    xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-web-ext_1_1.xsd"
    version="1.1">

    <reload-interval value="3"/>
    <context-root uri="ADRS" />
    <enable-directory-browsing value="true"/>
    <enable-file-serving value="true"/>
    <enable-reloading value="true"/>
    <enable-serving-servlets-by-class-name value="true" />

</web-ext>
```

Comment: I don't see the problem in web.xml. Now I changed the ibm-web-ext.xml to   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-ext
 xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-web-ext_3_0.xsd"
 version="1.0">
 I don't see the error but I see the "No grammar constraints (DTD or XML schema) detected for the document." warning in ibm-web-ext.xml

Comment: I have pasted the contents for `ibm-web-ext.xml`

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: Yes I got it. Thank you

Comment: Can I ignore this by changing it from warning to ignore in preferences? Will this be a good solution?

Comment: Great Thank you for your quick reply and help.